# Authentication Email/Password with Firebase sdk3 and Angularfire2

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I am new to Firebase, but I want to use it in my current angular2 project. I am stuck with Email-Password-Authentication using [Angularfire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2). As far as I do understand the API you have to call the `signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)` method of the `firebase.auth.Auth` object. I don't know how to get an instance of this 'Auth', though. 
I did find an [example](https://github.com/r-park/todo-angular2-firebase/blob/master/src/core/auth/auth-service.ts) for authentication in general. But the example does not use email/password authentication. I cannot find any example on how to call the aforementioned method in the right way.

I did find some JS-Examples. There, the 'Auth'-Object is injected somehow. This does not seem to work the way I tried it. This is what i got so far (not working):

main.ts

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [..., FIREBASE_PROVIDERS,
defaultFirebase({
    apiKey: "<>",
    authDomain: "<>",
    databaseURL: "<>",
    storageBucket: "<>",
}),firebaseAuthConfig({
    provider: AuthProviders.Password,
    method: AuthMethods.Password
}), AuthService])
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

auth.service.ts:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService{

private _authState: FirebaseAuthState = null;

constructor(private _fireAuth:FirebaseAuth, private _af:AngularFire, private _auth:Auth){
    _fireAuth.subscribe( (state:FirebaseAuthState) =>{
        this._authState = state;
    });
}

get authenticated():boolean{
    return this._authState !== null;
}

get id(): string {
    return this.authenticated ? this._authState.uid : '';
}

signIn(email:string, password:string):Promise<User>{
    return this._auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
}
...
```

My App does not even start -> Error `Cannot resolve all parameters for 'AuthService'(FirebaseAuth, AngularFire, ?)`. 
If I try to use `this._af.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)` the Typescript compiler complains: `error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.` Ignoring the compiler error and running the program results in an error `TypeError: this._af.auth is not a function`.

Thank you for your help!

`#AskFirebase`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, i still didnt find out how to use the signInWithEmailAndPassword method. I managed to login with email/password, though. You can just use

```
signIn(email:string, password:string){
  _fireAuth.login({
    email: email,
    password: password
  });
}
```

where _fireAuth is of type FirebaseAuth.